# Add value in variable to date php

Tags: php, date

If I have a number like -7 stored in a variable how can I modify a date in php by this amount. Here's what I have so far;

```
<?php 
    $the_date = '16 Mar 2018'; 
    $test_sum = '-7';
    $date = $the_date;
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = strtotime($test_sum, $date);
    echo date('d M Y', $date);
?>
```

But this just output's the initial date value.

Comment: -7 what? Unit-less numbers are meaningless. You can do most transformations inside `strtotime`

Comment: got ya! Need to add 'days'. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running:

```
date('d M Y', strtotime('16 Mar 2018 -7 days'))
```

would produce:

```
09 Mar 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

strtotime accepts "-7 day" as argument.
I think this may work:

```
$the_date = '16 Mar 2018'; 
$test_sum = '-7';
$date = strtotime($the_date);
$date = strtotime("$test_sum day", $date);
echo date('d M Y', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract days, you can simply use `'-7 days'`. If you don't specify the unit `strtotime()` probably doesn't subtracts days.

```
$the_date = '16 Mar 2018'; 
$test_sum = -7;
$date = strtotime(sprintf("%d days", $test_sum), strtotime($the_date));
echo date('d M Y', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following code :

```
$the_date = '16-Mar-2018'; 
$test_sum = '-7';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($the_date. $test_sum.' days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `strtotime()` what this function does is it gets the string containing an English date format and try to convert it into a Unix timestamp formate which is the number of seconds since 1 of January 1970 00:00:00.

This code should work for you:

```
date('d M Y', strtotime($the_date. $test_sum . ' days'));
```

This makes this `16 Mar 2018` to this `09 Mar 2018`

Hope that this helps.

More about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)